# Powershell: How can I dynamically iterate over nested json objects?

Tags: json, powershell

Suppose I have something like this:

```
    "config_service": {
        "config_service_1": {
            "service": "__service1__"
        },
        "config_service_2": {
            "service": "__service2__"
        }
    },
```

I am able to grab out the parent json by doing

```
$jsonMappings.config_service
```

But how can I dynamically iterate over each json value in there and do something like, for each object within config_service, extract value of key named 'service'? When I try doing ForEach-Object it treats the config service 1 and 2 as one big object.

Comment: You can use the *intrinsic* property of `PSObject` that exposes those values under one property: `$json.config_service.PSObject.Properties.Value`.

Comment: In short: Use `.psobject.Properties` to reflect on a given object's properties. The first linked duplicate shows how to do it for a single target object, the second 
shows how to walk an object graph recursively.